# What is the names of $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ linear equation system components?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Having  $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ .

What is the names of $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ linear equation system components?

Comment: I've heard it called the constant vector.

Comment: Now that the question has changed, I've heard $A$ called the coefficient matrix, $x$ the unknown vector, and $b$ the constant vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Elementary Linear Algebra by Venit and Bishop, we have:
$$A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$$
$A$ is the coefficient matrix of the system
$\vec{x}$ is the (column) vector of unknowns
$\vec{b}$ is the (column) of constants.

Granted, its probably not the most well-known book, but it's the one I have `;)`